# Combine two sqlite queries

Tags: sqlite

I have 3 tables in SQLite db - Products, CategoryProduct_MM (Categories of products) and Facing (Order of products). Products table contain PrdID (INTEGER), CategoryProduct_MM contain CategoryID (INTEGER) and PrdID (INTEGER), Facing contain CategoryID, PrdID and Order (all INTEGER). If Product's category exist in Facing table, i must sort products based on Order like this

```
SELECT p.* FROM Products p INNER JOIN Facing f ON p.PrdID = f.PrdID WHERE f.CategoryID = ? ORDER BY f.'Order';
```

In another case i must select from Products like this

```
SELECT p.* FROM Products p INNER JOIN CategoryProduct_MM cp ON p.PrdID = cp.PrdID WHERE cp.CategoryID = ?;
```

How to combine them in one query?

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: Sql union statement can be helpful here

Comment: @Mureinik added the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct query

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Products p 
INNER JOIN CategoryProduct_MM cp 
ON (p.PrdID = cp.PrdID AND cp.CategoryID = ?) 
LEFT JOIN Facing f 
ON (f.PrdID = cp.PrdID AND f.CategoryID = cp.CategoryID) 
ORDER BY f.'Order';
```